# What is the purpose of "no" Keyword in Sql Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I know about "not" keyword but its new for me. Please give me an use and example.

Comment: `NO` does not appear in the [list of reserved SQL Server keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  Can you add a documentation reference to your question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please check in ODBC Reserved Keywords from above same link

Comment: From the docs: "The following words are reserved for use in ODBC function calls. These words do not constrain the minimum SQL grammar; however, to ensure compatibility with drivers that support the core SQL grammar, applications should avoid using these keywords."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only reserved just-in-case some engine might use it, to ensure compatibility with drivers that support the core SQL grammar:

"The following words are reserved for use in ODBC function calls. These words do not constrain the minimum SQL grammar; however, to ensure compatibility with drivers that support the core SQL grammar, applications should avoid using these keywords."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2012

It's not only reserved by Microsoft.

https://firebirdsql.org/en/iso-9075-sql-standard-keywords-reserved-words/